# How do I uninstall Untangle Server?

Tags: security, uninstall, untangle

I cannot seem to get this application to uninstall from the control panel and I have no recollection of ever installing it.  Anyone know how to get rid of it?  I cannot seem to find any references to it in the services or the registry.  I suspect it may have been installed by malware of some sort.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The real [untangle server](http://www.untangle.com/) is a network gateway. If you haven't installed it you're right to be concerned. You should should look through this [page](http://www.michaelhorowitz.com/removespyware.html) on how to remove spyware, it runs through a lot of hints and step-by step analysis.

I would start with this step [How to fully de-gunk a PC of Crapware](http://blogs.zdnet.com/Ou/?p=547&page=2)

Comment: +1 bah, faster and better answer by 44 seconds ;)

Comment: @pavsaund It's not like the first page of users are at all competitive :-)